# Keras Functional API Multiple Input Shape Errors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation, flatten

My goal is to use a CNN to go through a picture, then add an array of extra data before the dense layers.

```
picIn = keras.Input(shape=x[0].shape)
conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,padding='same',use_bias=False)(picIn)
batch1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
leaky1 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch1)
conv2 = layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,padding='same',use_bias=False)(leaky1)
batch2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
leaky2 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch2)
cdrop1 = layers.Dropout(.20)(leaky2)
conv3= layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',use_bias=False)(cdrop1)
batch3 = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
leaky3 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch3)
conv4 = layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,padding='same',use_bias=False)(leaky3)
batch4 = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv4)
leaky4 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch4)
cdrop2 = layers.Dropout(.20)(leaky4)
flat1 = layers.Flatten()(cdrop2)

rtheta1 = rtheta[trainCut]
rtheta1 = rtheta1.reshape(467526,1)
rtheta2 = rtheta[testCut]
rtheta2 = rtheta2.reshape(82247,1)

ip2 = keras.Input(shape=rtheta1.shape)
flat2 = layers.Flatten()(ip2)

merge = layers.Concatenate()([flat1,flat2])
hidden1 = layers.Dense(512,use_bias=False)(merge)
batch5 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
leaky5 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch5)
ddrop1 = layers.Dropout(.20)(leaky5)
hidden2 = layers.Dense(512,use_bias=False)(ddrop1)
batch6 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden2)
leaky6 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch6)
ddrop2 = layers.Dropout(.20)(leaky6)
hidden3 = layers.Dense(512,use_bias=False)(merge)
batch7 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
leaky7 = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=.3)(batch5)
ddrop3 = layers.Dropout(.20)(leaky5)
output = layers.Dense(1)(ddrop3)
model = keras.Model(inputs = [picIn,ip2], outputs = output)

H = model.fit(x =[ x[trainCut],rtheta[trainCut]],y= y[trainCut],batch_size=args.bsize,validation_data=([x[testCut],rtheta[testCut]], y[testCut]),epochs=args.epochs)
```

I always get an error related to the shape of the inputs

**Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 473926 but received input with shape [None, 6401]**

**Model was constructed with shape (None, 467526, 1) for input Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 467526, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 1).**

Im confused on what exactly to do here.
x[traincut] is a matrix of size (467526,10,10,2)
rtheta1 is (467526,1) and so is y[traincut]

The validation data is the same except it is 82247 instead of 467526.

I have tried it without flattening after ip2 and I get a different error but I think the core issue is still the same.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The data was not the right shape, obviously, but I figured out how to fix it.

Comment: Are you ensuring that all of your training data's shape is uniform before you put it through and into the first tensor?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries! I'll post my reply in the answer section so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you ensuring that all of your training data's shape is uniform before you put it through and into the first tensor?